# How do I interpolate a Perl hash element in a string?

Tags: perl, string, hash

How do I print a hash from within a string, as in

```
print "\n[*] Query : $select { query }";
```

versus

```
print "\n[*] Query : " . $select { query };
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may need to eliminate the extra spaces:

```
print "\n[*] Query : $select{query}";
```

With a space after `$select`, Perl thinks that you are done with the interpolation of that variable, and treats the following text (including the curly braces) literally.

Comment: What if the key was yet again a variable : print "\n[*] Query : $select{$query}"; ?

Comment: That should work fine too (as long as you don't put any extra spaces in the interpolation).